# Tradfi grief ongoing

Tags: ikea-tradfri

I seemingly cannot add 2 lights with separate controllers to one room, am I missing something, when I want to add a second light it wants me to control them together.

Also it seems Alexa has dissowned the tradfri lights I have tried resetting re installing but no joy

Comment: Can you give more details? For instance, what you mean by "dissowned "

Comment: This should be 2 totally separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

A "room" in Ikea speak is the combination of a control device<sup>*</sup> and one or more bulbs.

If you have 2 distinct set of bulbs+controllers those are separate "rooms"

<sup>*</sup>You can pair multiple controllers to the same set of bulbs